# Why is my inner loop is not running in this code?

Tags: java

I am trying to run this code but i am not able to understand why my inner loop `for(int j=N-1; j<=0; j--)` is not running.
It is directly printing 0 from the outer loop.
I am beginner in java and i tried everything debugging the code with println but I am not able to get it.
For this input:-

```
3
21 3 6
11
20 15 5 7 10 4 2 1 3 6 8
```

I should be able to get answer as 1 0 3 0 0 3 3 2 2 0 0 .
But i am getting answer as 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .
Please help me where i am getting wrong in this to get right answer.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.* ;
import java.io.* ;

class HolesBalls {


    public static void calculatePosition(long[] diaHoles, long[] diaBalls, int N, int M) {
        HashMap<Long, Long> holeMeasure = new HashMap<>();

        for(int i=0; i<N ; i++) {
                holeMeasure.put(diaHoles[i], (long) 0);

        }


        for(int i=0; i<M ; i++) {
            int flag = 0;
            for(int j=N-1; j<=0 ; j--) { 
                if(diaBalls[i] <= diaHoles[j] && holeMeasure.get(diaHoles[j]) != j+1) {
                    System.out.print(j+1+" ");
                    holeMeasure.put(diaHoles[j], holeMeasure.get(diaHoles[j])+1);
                    flag = 1 ;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag == 0) {
                System.out.print("0 ");
            }
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        String[] diaHole = br.readLine().split(" ");
        int M = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        String[] diaBall = br.readLine().split(" ");
        long[] diaBalls = new long[M];
        long[] diaHoles = new long[N];
        for(int i=0; i<N ; i++) {
            diaHoles[i] = Long.parseLong(diaHole[i]);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<M ; i++) {
            diaBalls[i] = Long.parseLong(diaBall[i]);
        }

        calculatePosition(diaHoles, diaBalls, N, M);
    }

}
```

Comment: Probably because `j` is never less than or equal to 0.

Comment: Use the symbolic debugger and step through the code, examining the value of the loop variable and the limits.

Comment: The condition in the second for loop should be j>=0

Comment: I am getting an extra space at the end also. How do i remove it ? For eg:- ```1 0 3 0 0 3 3 2 2 0 0 (getting extra space here)```

Answer (score 4):

It is because you have mistakenly given the wrong condition inside your inner loop.

This should be changed :

```
for(int j=N-1; j<=0 ; j--)
```

to this :

```
for(int j=N-1; j>=0 ; j--)
```

Comment: Wow thanks, i spent like 2 hours and this was the mistake.

Comment: btw also i am getting an extra space at the end. how do i remove it ?

Comment: can't see any statement which could cause that, have you shared your full code?

Comment: There's nothing in the code you shared that might be causing it, please share a screenshot if the problem persists.